# Dump file was copied into RDS Oracle but can't import it

Tags: oracle, rds

Here's my case: I received a dump file from my customer. I don't have access to source DB to check how they created it. 
So i created a new source by launching EC2 windows, install Oracle Express, put dump file into DATA_PUMP_DIR folder on this EC2.
Then i managed to copy this dump file into RDS Oracle and confirmed it existed in RDS.

But when executing command line to import it into RDS, i got error:

```
impdp masteruser/masterpass@rsinstance.citmdnq1zckt.ap-northeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/ORCL DIRECTORY=DATA_PUMP_DIR DUMPFILE=sample_copied5.dmp table_exists_action=replace full=y;
```

Basically, in RDS i didn't mess with anything including create user, schema.
How can i make this work?

Here's error

```
   Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
ORA-31684: Object type USER:"CLOUDTOSAI" already exists
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
ORA-31685: Object type SYSTEM_GRANT:"CLOUDTOSAI" failed due to insufficient privileges. Failing sql is:
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "CLOUDTOSAI"
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01924: role 'CONNECT' not granted or does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "CONNECT" TO "CLOUDTOSAI"
ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:
ORA-01924: role 'AQ_USER_ROLE' not granted or does not exist
Failing sql is:
 GRANT "AQ_USER_ROLE" TO "CLOUDTOSAI"
```

Comment: Could you add the error details?

Comment: I added error on my first post.

Comment: Maybe they didn't create it using Export Data Pump, but *original* EXP utility? If so, try to import it using IMP instead. Though, why don't you simply ask them which export utility they used to create that DMP file?

Comment: Thank you. I'm gonna ask them soon but currently, if i don't know how they created dump file i can't import it?

Comment: I heard that they use Data Dump only.

Comment: You mean user on 2nd source? If so, i granted it. Anyway, i tried to import dump file on Oracle Express first and it didn't work too. I tried with impdp, it said: 
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39000: bad dump file specification
ORA-39088: file name cannot contain a path specification

impdp khoi/khoi@localhost file=C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\datadump\201712010305_CLOUDTOSAI.dmp full=y;

Comment: No mysteries in that error message. Remove the path from the filename.

Comment: @Rene I fixed the command line. Now i got another errors.

Comment: Run the import as system user. Seems your masteruser doesn't have all required privileges.

Comment: I did use system user.